# Is the following function continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x) = \begin{cases} \ \ \ x, &x\in\mathbb{Q}, \\ -x,\ & \mathrm{otherwise.}\end{cases}$

Is $f(x)$
continuous at $x = 0$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

This function is continuous only at $0$. To show continuity at $0$ observe that $|f(x)-f(0)|=|f(x)|=|x|$. About discontinuity at any $x_0\ne 0$, the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ does not exist.